# H2 database update always put elements to the end

Tags: angularjs, pagination, spring-boot, h2

I'm using a H2 database and I noticed, that every time if I update a element, it is put to the end. In MySQL it stays on the same position.

Is there a way to do that in H2 too?

Spring Boot paging | AngularJS

Comment: AFAIK, SQL makes no guarantees about the ordering of the rows in a table. If you care about the order of the results in a query, you should use an `ORDER BY` clause.